# Decry vs. Call (someone) out

Tags: synonyms

**To decry** means

> [Publicly denounce](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decry).

**To call (someone) out** means, especially in American English

> [Draw critical attention to someone's unacceptable actions or
>   behaviour](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/call_someone_out).

As far as I am concerned, these two verbs are, based on these dictionary entries, synonymous with each other.

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: their meaning is [close but not identical](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-millennials-use-the-term-to-call-out-when-they-mean-to-say-to-denounce)

Comment: They're not synonymous. In your context *to decry* does mean to *denounce*. That is always negative; always aggressive.

My experience of US American English is limited to print, screen and extrapolation yet I think *called her out* on… preferable to *calling him out* for… and *she called him on his claim…* better.

That's to say, *call out* retains the old sense of *challenge* which might be negative but needn't be more than assertive.